# Hair particles unaffected by mist?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

In Blender 2.69 I can't figure out why hair particles are unaffected by mist.
I'm using tangent shading if that makes a difference.

Does anyone know how to fix this? (see image)
Thanks!

[image: Problem with hair particles]

UPDATE: Ok, I think I figured it out somewhat. And yes, I am using blender render, not cycles, sorry about that.

If I turn off 'Strand render' in the particle settings it works!

[image: Strand render off]

But the hairs, or needles in this case, don't render quite as well as with strand render on...

[image: Strand render on]

If someone knows a way around this, that would be great to know. But I'm content with the way it looks either way. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you using BI or Cycles? And is it possible you could upload a .blend?

Comment: Strand works fine for me.. Is it possible you post a screenshot of your material and particle settings or better, a blendfile?

Comment: @gandalf3, to be honest, when I tried it just now with strand it worked. But I'm still getting the same problem with my trees as before. Here's a .blend... [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108957850/MistTest.blend)

Comment: That is strange.. I got better results when using the mist pass and disabling mist in the materials. [**Example file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26609)

Comment: That's a great alternative, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you had the "Use mist" option on the particles material. You could post some file showing the problem. The image had some post process?

Answer (score 0):

It might be of use to others seeking an answer, but in my case it's because my material for the leaves has Z Transparency instead of Raytrace. Changing it to Raytrace immediately applies mist to them. (Both cases has "Use Mist" checked, and I didn't use a particle)

[image]

[image]