# Wiil a speedtree cast shadow in cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light, shadows

I want to know how can I cast a shadow of a tree to my render.
If I use a speed tree in front of the light, will it cast shadow to the objects?
Or should I place a 3D tree model?
Or else should I place a plane with tree texture?\

Which one would be better?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. What's a "speed tree"?

Comment: So I gather that SpeedTree is software for modeling plants... that's about all I know from 10 seconds of searching online. But if that software generates textures and UV maps it's just a matter of setting up those textures correctly with Cycles nodes. I'm inclined to think it should work. Why don't you give it a try? Sounds like you have a pretty specific workflow, so the best thing to do would be to test it out.

Comment: Also, as a general tip when dealing with lots of foliage: make sure your max transparency bounces are turned up high enough or you may encounter [problems like this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38111/what-causes-this-mist-pass-glitch).

Comment: It will likely cast shadows. If you came up with an answer, please post it so that future visitors can get help from it.