# Transparent BSDF cause noise in depth layer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, transparency, render-passes, depth-map

I have system that consumes depth and RGB output of Cycles renderer.
I can observe noise in depth maps when I use `transparent BSDF` with `Mix shader` and RGBA texture. Let's look at sample simple shader:
[image: Sample shader with mix BSDF and transparent BSDF]

That shader is giving material that is transparent with level of transparency given by alpha channel of texture.
I am not happy with depth image, especially on edges (white dots):

[image]
Two factor has to be present to "depth" noise appears:

- There must be some other object behind the part that is transparent.
- The noise seems to be absent when alpha channel has only value 255 or 0.

A this moment I found some solutions:

- using mist pass
- using material override

First solution seems to give depth values in some bizzare scale (I need it linear in meters, like Z-pass) and the noise is still present.
Second solution is not acceptable, because removes desired feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is normal behavior, same issue appears in [mist pass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38111).
During mist pass / z-pass mixa shaders with transparent shader cause that some of rays do not contribute to image output. I resolved it introducing contrast node before mix shader to keep mixing rate 0 or 1.